# HTML Input values are non numeric values

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hook-form

So, Im trying to push values to my backend but for some reason my values are thrown as an error back at me with `Expected type Float. Float cannot represent non numeric value: \"33\""`

I am using `react-hook-forms` and Ive set it the following (This is a custom component that I am expanding on to)

```
    <Input
            label="Cost"
            min={0}
            placeholder="Enter Amount"
            name="cost"
            type="number"
            register={register}
            required={{
              required: 'Please enter a number',
               valueAsNumber: true,
              pattern: {
                value: currencyRegex,
                message: 'Please enter a valid number',
              },
            }}
            error={errors.cost && <Error message={errors.cost.message} />}
          />
```

This works but the issue is here I can type in ANY number even if its negative or has special characters, it will accept it and if I remove  `valueAsNumber: true,` then the regex works but I get this error then `Expected type Float. Float cannot represent non numeric value: \"33\""`

Ive tried so many things to fix this but with no real success and Ive been stuck on this for hours. Tried looking on the internet for some solution but again It just feels like a waste of time, because of such a specific issue. If anyone has a solution/fix I would appreciate it

Comment: The `min` and `step` attributes of `<Input>` might help you here, you should be able to set `min` to 0, and `step` to `0.01` since it's a currency.

Comment: I tried `min` & step`  it works with up and down arrow but typing a value overrides it and you can then type in -99999 and it will accept it

Comment: You need a masked input with a pattern for currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So react-hook-forms has a nifty thing called validate that you can use with register so you can then say the following

Its not exactly a fix for regex and string values but atleast you can validate the values with a message depending on your needs and it works with `valueAsNumber`

```
   <Input
            label="Provide a number"
            placeholder="Number value here"
            name="number"
            type="number"
            required={{
              valueAsNumber: true,
              required: 'Please enter a number',
            ### Here if you add this then the value will never be a minus value
              min: {
                value: 1,
                message: 'Please enter a valid number (The number must be greater than 0)',
              },
            }}
            error={errors.cost && <Error message={errors.cost.message} />}
          />
```

Hope this helps anyone out there with the same issue